# FormType & method repository

Tags: doctrine, repository, symfony, distinct

I have a problem with my FormType. I want to display data and thanks to the querybuilder make a distinction. Problem when I call my method with a -> select ('t.nomVern') I have "Warning: spl_object_hash () expects parameter 1 to be object, string given" as an error message.

I do not understand why.

My FormType ObservationType:

```
<?php

namespace ObservationBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;
use ImportBundle\Repository\TaxrefRepository;
use ImportBundle\Entity\Taxref;

class ObservationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('date', DateType::class, array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'html5' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'Choisir la date de l\'observation',
                )
            ))
            ->add('latitude', TextType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'Latitude ex : 31.85322'
                )
            ))
            ->add('longitude', TextType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'Longitude ex : 33.55555'
                )
            ))
            ->add('nombre', IntegerType::class)

            ->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
                'allow_delete' => false, // not mandatory, default is true
                'download_link' => false, // not mandatory, default is true
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'Votre image'
                )
            ))
            ->add('valide', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('commentaire', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('gpsAffiche', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('meteo', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('saison', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('typeSaisie', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('precipitation', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('periode', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('environnement', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('sensibilite', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('comportement', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('species', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Espèce observée :',
                'class' => 'ImportBundle\Entity\Taxref',
                'choice_label' => 'nomVern',
                'query_builder' => function(TaxrefRepository $qb){
                    return $qb->distinctTaxref();
                }
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ObservationBundle\Entity\Observation'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'observationbundle_observation';
    }


}
```

And my repository :

```
<?php

namespace ImportBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class TaxrefRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * Pagination liste des especes
     * @param int $page
     * @param int $max
     * @return Paginator
     */
    public function findByPage($page = 1, $max = 8)
    {
        if(!is_numeric($page)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                '$page must be an integer ('.gettype($page).' : '.$page.')'
            );
        }

        if(!is_numeric($page)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                '$max must be an integer ('.gettype($max).' : '.$max.')'
            );
        }

        $dql = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');
        $dql->orderBy('t.id', 'DESC');

        $firstResult = ($page - 1) * $max;

        $query = $dql->getQuery();
        $query->setFirstResult($firstResult);
        $query->setMaxResults($max);

        $paginator = new Paginator($query);

        if(($paginator->count() <=  $firstResult) && $page != 1) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Page not found');
        }

        return $paginator;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder
     */
    public function distinctTaxref()
    {


        return $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->select('t.nomVern')
            ->distinct(true)
            ->orderBy('t.nomVern', 'ASC');

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help and sorry for my bad english :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this part of code

```
return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select(array('t.nomVern'))
        ->distinct(true)
        ->orderBy('t.nomVern', 'ASC');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, since you're using `EntityType`, Symfony expects to have an array of objects, whereas you select a single column which produces an array of strings.

Can you try selecting an object as a whole:

```
return $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->select('t')
    ->distinct(true)
    ->orderBy('t.nomVern', 'ASC');
```

Does this work?

Comment: Hello,

I no longer have the error message. On the other hand, the distinction does not work. 
I have the same result without the query_builder